# How to generate/print reports on the client side

Tags: reporting, jasper-reports

I'd like to know, if is it possible to generate and print a report ( using jasper report for example) on the client side?

Answer (score 0):

They would have to have jasper report and java installed. I suppose you could push an applet to the client with all the necessary jars and stuff.

Why would you do this?

Comment: the thing is that the server is far away from the office that uses my web application, and I think it would be a good idea that the users can generate and print their reports when they need them,without having to go to the server room, which I think would be such a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

This should be do with every (most) reporting solutions. You need a Java client that run as applet or Java applet or you render as PDF and print with the PDF viewer.